# Ember.js and Twitter Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm trying to deploy the [popover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) using ember.js but not sure how to do it.

The contents of the popover must be an element of ember to interact with it.

I've been watching https://github.com/jzajpt/ember-bootstrap but does not include the popover element.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you try to do will never work, because if your mouse leaves the control, the popover will go away!

```
App.Popover = Ember.View.extend({
     name: 'myPopover',
     template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div class="popover" {{bindAttr name="name"}}><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title">test</h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>')         
});

App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this._super();
        var self = this;                
        Ember.run.schedule('actions', this, function() {
           self.$().popover({
                title: 'title', 
                content: 'content',
                template: $('div[name="myPopover"]')
            });     
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in the didInsertElement method of your view you can do something like this

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$().popover({
        title: self.get('tooltipTitle'), 
        content: self.get('tooltipContent')
    });     
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the contents of the property 'content' of popover should be a view of Ember to introduce into the popover an user interaction.